# Referencing single arbitrary cell using Excel structured reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I reference a single cell in a table ***using structured references***. For example, for the following table named Prices:

```
    A        B
__________________
1| NAME    PRICE
2| apple    1.5
3| orange   2.3
4| pear     3.4
```

How do I reference the cell B3?

Comment: From where? if you are referencing it from C3, or D3 or Sheet99!Z3 you can use the implicit intersection style of Table1[@Price]. If from anywhere else, see answer already posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to reference row by value in another column, or row number, you can use:

`FILTER(table1[Price],table1[NAME]="orange")`

OR

`INDEX(table1[PRICE],2)`

Comment: I was hoping for something more array-addressing-kind-of, like table1[PRICE][2]. @Microsoft, I'm very disappointed...